# How to update data stored in Registry

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I had a problem modifying the data in the Registry Editor, and I tried to modify it, but I couldn't, please help

```
extern crate winreg;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;
use winreg::enums::*
use winreg::RegKey;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
//creat registry
    let hkcu = RegKey::predef(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
    let path = Path::new("TEST").join("somone");
    let (key, disp) = hkcu.create_subkey(&path)?;
// add key and value
     key.set_value("Test_1", &1234567890u32)?;
//delete key and value
     key.delete_value("hello");
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: @AliAwad I know you can see your screen, but we can't, so please tell us what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some minor issues:

1. Semicolon missed in the import
2. Deleting some other key than you created. You created `Test_1` and tried to delete `hello`.
3. I'm not sure if you added `winreg` to `Cargo.toml`. Anyway with [Rust version 1.62.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/06/30/Rust-1.62.0.html) you can use `cargo add winreg`.

Also, please note that since [edition 2018](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/whats-the-difference-between-extern-crate-and-write-into-cargo-toml/46482), you no more need to use `extern crate`, just simply use `use`.

```
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;
use winreg;
use winreg::enums::*;
use winreg::RegKey;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    //creat registry
    let hkcu = RegKey::predef(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
    let path = Path::new("TEST").join("othman");
    let (key, disp) = hkcu.create_subkey(&path)?;
    // add key and value
    key.set_value("Test_1", &1234567890u32)?;
    //delete key and value
    key.delete_value("Test_1");
    // add key and value again
    key.set_value("Test_1", &1234567891u32)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not solve my main problem which is updating the data, can you help me with it??

Comment: I updated the code, can you try now please

Comment: If it's not working, the problem might be somewhere else.